# Displayed Numerical Precision in R / RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, precision

I'm having a problem where the displayed precision of a numerical result sometimes reverts to rounded-off integer format. For instance, some days, a simple calculation like this generates the expected decimal-precision result:

```
> x <- 344.5 - .25
> x
[1] 344.25
```

But then I can come back another day, try again and get:

```
> 344.5 - .25
> x
[1] 344
```

I've verified via subtraction of terms that the hidden precision is still there: so it may display 344, for instance, but the value of 344.25 is still contained in the variable.

I can't figure out what's changing (or how to control it) so that it just stays one way consistently, preferably with some displayed precision to the right of the decimal point.

Comment: What is the value of `getOption("digits")`?

Comment: `> getOption("digits")
[1] 3`

Comment: In other words, it's 3

Comment: There's your problem.  Set it back to its default 7 with `options(digits = 7)`

Comment: Got it. Thank you! (Any idea what's resetting it? I'm thinking something in RStudio upon startup...

Comment: And if a setting like that is changing at different times, I think it may mean you have a `.Rprofile` file somewhere that is changing the setting?

Comment: Thanks, Marius. I'll look into that.

Comment: I think you can see if that file exists with `file.exists(".Rprofile")`

Comment: I got `FALSE`   I guess I better create one!

Answer (score 0):

As you stated in the comments, you have a `getOption("digits")` value of 3.

```
options(digits = 3)
344.5 - 0.25
# [1] 344
```

Resetting the `digits` option to its default value of 7 will give you what you want.

```
options(digits = 7)
344.5 - 0.25
# [1] 344.25
```

You can read more about options in `help(options)`.